# Dynamic Bootstrap Tabs using Django

Tags: django

I have 2 tables in mysql. One is main table which keep title and title will be shown as tab header and there is one content table which will shown as content of each tab. There is foreign key between 2 tables. But i couldn't print related content under correct tab.

This is my code that i show tab headers.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {% for title in titles %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="{{ title.id }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ title.name }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ title.name }}" aria-selected="true">{{ title.name }}</a>
          </li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

End this is part for tab content

```
 <div class="tab-content" id="SideBarTabContent">
 <!-- tab content -->
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="should print header name" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="should print header name">
     <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
      {% for item in contents %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ item.id }}">
             {{ item.name }} 
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And there is django code:

```
def home(request):
    titles = Headers.objects.all()[:10]
    contents = content.objects.select_related('Content')
    return render_to_response('main.html', {'titles' : titles, 'contents': contents})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved issue by generating html at view.py. I will use this until received your feedback. But i have another issue now. In my site, i show this tab in the left sidebar and left sidebar is static page for all. It should be in every page. But i am able to render_to_response only for main.html now and it is failing when open other pages. How can show when i browse other pages?

```
def home(request):
modules = Headers.objects.all()[:10]
m=0
i=0
tabHtml =''
contentHtml =''
while m < len(modules):
    tabHtml += '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="'+modules[m].ModuleName+'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#'+modules[m].ModuleName+'" role="tab" aria-controls="'+modules[m].ModuleName+'" aria-selected="true">'+modules[m].ModuleName+'</a></li>'
    contentHtml +='<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="'+ modules[m].ModuleName + '" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="'+ modules[m].ModuleName + '-tab">'
    moduleitems = Content.objects.select_related('Item').filter(Item_id =modules[m].id)
    while i < len(moduleitems):
        contentHtml +='<ul class="nav flex-column mb-2"><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#"><span data-feather="home"></span>'+str(moduleitems[i].id)+'<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li></ul></div>'
        i = i+1
    m = m+1
return render_to_response('main.html', {'tabContentHtml' : contentHtml, 'tabHtml': tabHtml})
```

Comment: render() issue solved by creating new project. I didn't understand why but it worked. Also i am able to call sidebar page in every page loaded.